# PHP Include and Class Scope

Tags: php, function, class, scope, include

I am having a problem with var scope in a script iam developing, right now i think i will have to rewrite all my methods but lets see if someone can point me to the right direction.

file1.php

```
<?php
$db = new SystemDB();
include('file2.php');
someFile2Function();
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
function someFile2Function(){
    $db = new Database;
    include('class.php');
    $class = new CustomClass();
    $class->someMethod();
}
?>
```

class.php

```
<?php
class CustomClass {

    function someMethod(){
        global $db; <-- this var is the file1.php var and not the file2.php function var
        // execute some query
    }

}
?>
```

My problem is that inside the class the var $db that is using is the one in file1.php and not the one in someFile2Function() in file2.php.

Is there a way to use global $db that uses the var $db declared on someFile2Function();

Thanks.

Comment: Dont use `globals` like that in classes. It totally destroys the encapsulation. Pass it as a param to `someclass::__construct($db)` and keep it as a property of someclass

Comment: I know it was my mistake! i am asking to see if there is a way that i dont have to rewrite all classes and methods to pass the $db object to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

as @RiggsFolly mention it's not a good idea to gave global in class, since there are conflict possibilities. Use it as parameter, that change dynamically, depend on what method/object calling it.

```
 function someMethod($db){
     var_dump($db);
  }
```

And also rather move function in file2.php to function from the class, if this function only needed by this class

Comment: I created the file2.php function just to try to use the function scope for the class but that doesnt seems to work.